# Easy plotting data in python with Android

Tags: android, python, plot, qpython

Hy guys!

I've been looking for the easiest way to produce an xy-plot using python with android  (qpython2 or 3) but I couldn't find any.
I considered

- using matplotlib, but apparently no version for android was released
- using droidplot, either via python modules or via command line (eventually to be called via python), but I didn't find modules or bash commannds which can be used.
- creating a JPG where to plot pixel by pixel (I don t really want to do that!! Even if it possibly works).

Any help from you?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qpython does not support matplotlib and droidplot currently, but we will consider adding the libraries in the future .By the way,we are developing a new version。